# How to update JIRA issue reporter from Python

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I'm trying to update the reporter of an issue using the JIRA Python API (version 1.0.3).

I am signed in (using basic auth) as a user who has full permissions, and I am trying to do it for an issue which I myself have created. The issue is successfully created, however when I call the update command, it changes the assignee rather than the reporter.

Any ideas? I have tried searching, but to no avail.

Here's my full code:

```
jira = JIRA('http://jiraurl.com/', basic_auth=('user', 'pass'))

new_issue = jira.create_issue(project='ER', summary='summary', description='desc', issuetype={'name': 'Custom Issue Type'})

new_issue.update(reporter='new_user')
```

Comment: Do you have the `Modify Reporter` permissions?

Comment: @Forge Yes, I have `Modify Report` permissions. `new_issue.update(reporter={'name': 'new_user'})` worked, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax should be 
`new_issue.update(reporter={'name': 'new_user'})`

The [Jira](http://jira.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#issues) documentation specify a similar example for the field `assignee`.

Comment: This oddly gives me the error "Reporter is required."

Comment: @Cerin for the newer Jira servers you have to specify the users accountID. `fields = {}` `fields["reporter"] = {"id": target_user_account_id}` `target_issue.update(fields=fields)`.
You can get all the user accountID with: `server.search_users(query="?", maxResults=500)`